# Converting command line output with UTF-8 byte-string to Unicode codepoint in Go

Tags: go, unicode, utf-8

I am running an executable from Go via os.Exec, which gives me the following output: `(\\xe2\\x96\\xb2)`. The output contains a UTF-8 byte string, which I want to convert to the corresponding Unicode codepoint (U+25B2). What I am expecting to see, or trying to convert to is: "(▲)".
I have looked at this entry in the Go Blog (https://blog.golang.org/strings), but it starts out with an Interpreted string literal, whereas the command output seems to be a Raw string literal. I have tried `strconv.Quote` and `strconv.Unquote`, which does not achieve what I'm looking for.

Comment: Can you show an example of what you're trying to do? Since go uses utf8 for strings, it will interpret the bytes correctly by default: https://play.golang.org/p/u3JkywATmPR

Comment: I may not have been clear enough with the above description. The output string that I'm getting is not interpreted automatically, because it behaves like a Raw string literal. See here: https://play.golang.org/p/TI-41dEWZaM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`strconv`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/) package to parse the string literal containing the escape sequences.

The quick and dirty way is to simply add the missing quotes and interpret it as a quoted string using [`strconv.Unquote`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#Unquote)

```
s := `\xe2\x96\xb2`
s, err := strconv.Unquote(`"` + s + `"`)
```

You can also directly parse the string one character at a time (which is what `Unquote` does internally), using [`strconv.UnquoteChar`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#UnquoteChar)

```
s := `\xe2\x96\xb2`
buf := make([]byte, 0, 3*len(s)/2)
for len(s) > 0 {
    c, _, ss, err := strconv.UnquoteChar(s, 0)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    s = ss
    buf = append(buf, byte(c))
}
s = string(buf)
```

https://play.golang.org/p/6SDij9d-aRr